# How to Run each file in the directory by adding the file name in RUN_Comand provided

Tags: python, bash, git-bash, calabash, bash-completion

I have bunch of `.sv` files in the following directory `/home/vs/vs_work2/Miss.Chim_DEPB`and I want to run the following command with each file name from the above directory

```
make sim TB=depb/sim/utb/epb_uvm_tb.json TC= **USE_FILE_NAME_From_ABOVE_Directory**
```

and keep the result of each file after the run into a separate file along with its files name that it ran with.

**This what I tried**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/vs/vs_work2/Miss.Chim_DEPB/*.sv

NUM_OF_FILES= ls /home/vs/vs_work2/Miss.Chim_DEPB/*.sv | wc -l   # this will lst number of files in that directory

declare -a vendec[NUM_OF_FILES]  # declared array "-a" is used for index array

arraylength=${#vendec[@]}


for f in $FILES
do
  #echo -n "" > vendec[*].txt  #to empty file
  
  vendec[i]
  
  echo "$f" >> vendec.txt
  
  
done
```

Comment: What is the error you are running into? I see an "i" variable being called with vendec - where is that defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following one-liner:

```
ls /home/vs/vs_work2/Miss.Chim_DEPB/*.sv | xargs -I {} bash -c "make sim TB=depb/sim/utb/epb_uvm_tb.json TC={} && echo {} >> vendec.txt"
```

It will list all `.sv` files in `/home/vs/vs_work2/Miss.Chim_DEPB/` and then, for each file, it will run the `make sim TB=depb/sim/utb/epb_uvm_tb.json TC={}` command with the `{}` placeholder being replaced with a file from the directory, and if that succeeds, it will write the name of the file at the end of the `vendec.txt` file.

Note that you can use the `-P` option of `xargs` to have multiple runs of the `make sim ....` command in parallel.